# Java program is not writing all the records to the output file using the BufferedWriter

Tags: java

This below code is not able to write more than 29499 lines in the output file. More over the last line was printed only half. I have verified there is no issue with the program as the program is print all the 25000 lines in console.

```
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/json/Sample.json");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/json/output.json");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String line=br.readLine();
        if (line == null) 
        {
            br.close();
            fr.close();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
        while (line!=null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            bw.write(record+"\n");
            line=br.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a proper [mcve]. Here we have some code that doesn't make sense - you read `line` but write `record`. You create a `Gson` object but don't use it. You don't close the resources (readers and writers).

Comment: For a start, add fw.flush() and fw.close() after the while loop.

Comment: Actually, only `bw.close()` would suffice. Flush is unnecessary, and closing just the `FileReader` will not flush or close the `BufferedReader` that uses it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: you are right, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You only close and flush your readers & writers if the *first* line is null. You presumably instead want to do this after your loop completes, which will ensure that (exceptions aside) they'll always close.

Even better, use the [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to avoid having to close / flush them manually at all - this will also handle the case where an exception it thrown.

Comment: Writing `your writers` would make the answer perfect?

Comment: @Michal Oops. Good spot.

Comment: After adding the flush() after the loop worked fine for me. Thanks.